# htaccess redirect appending old url to new

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Website is using expression engine, trying to add some simple 301 redirects using the below code;

```
Redirect 301 /contact-us/ http://www.website.co.uk/get-in-touch
```

This is returning the following url;

```
http://www.website.co.uk/get-in-touch?contact-us
```

I cannot find why this is doing this, I have also tried;

```
RewriteRule ^/contact-us/$ http://www.website.co.uk/get-in-touch [R=301]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/contact-us/?$ http://www.website.co.uk/get-in-touch
```

Both return the same result, the htaccess as a whole;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    #enforce the www's
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

RewriteRule ^/contact-us/$ http://www.website.co.uk/get-in-touch [R=301]
#RedirectMatch 301 ^/contact-us/?$ http://www.website.co.uk/get-in-touch
#Redirect 301 /contact-us/ http://www.website.co.uk/get-in-touch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `RewriteRule` appears to trick you.

A simple switch in the order should fix it. My general rule of thumb: External redirects first, internal rewrites second.

So in your case:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect /contact-us to /get-in-touch
    RewriteRule ^contact-us(/?)$ /get-in-touch [L,R=301]

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    #enforce the www's
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: When trying this, take care to open up your browser's dev tools and disable caching, because 301 redirects are cached.